# get regex to work in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression pattern,

```
From: ["<][^>]*>
```

I need it to work in java and the double quotes is producing an error. When I try and escape it like so

```
From: [\"<][^>]*>
```

it does not produce the correct result. Does anyone know how to handle double quotes in java for regular expressions? Thanks

Comment: Please see the updated error http://i.imgur.com/hPVhV.png

Comment: You can also use http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html . This is a good regex tester and it will also show the escaped form in java. Eclipse also has an option to automatically escape pasted string literals.

Answer (score 5):

The `\` character in Java String literals is a reserved escape character, so to add a regex escape character into a Java literal String object one must Escape the Escape :)

Eg. `\\"`  will result in a regex of `\"` which will find double quote characters.

**EDIT:** One thing that I forgot was that the double quote character is also a reserved character for a Java string literalas well!  Because of this the `\` for the regex must be escaped as well as the `"` character.

The actual Java string literal will look like this `String regex = "\\\"";`

Comment: Yes, thats what I did but that will not complile in java. http://i.imgur.com/hPVhV.png

Comment: @medium That is because you ALSO have to escape the double quote character as that is a reserved character for Java String literals!  So you will actually need `\\\"`.

Comment: `"` has no special meaning in a regex.  You only have to escape it to get it past Java's string-literal parsing: `"\""`.  Like any other non-special, non-alphanumeric character, you MAY escape it in the regex, too: `"\\\""`.  The regex parser will see that as a single backslash followed by a quotation mark, and it will ignore the backslash.